# Retrieve warnings with INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, go

I need to insert a lot of values into a MySQL table. Some of them might cause an error, but I still want the valid ones to be inserted. Consequently, I'm using an `INSERT IGNORE` query.

```
query := "INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable "
query += "(uniquekey, someotherfield) "
query += "VALUES "

var params []interface{} 

for _, element := range elements {
    query += "(?, ?),"
    params = append(params, element.UniqueKey, element.SomeOtherField)
}

_, err := db.Exec(query[:len(query)-1] + ";", params...)
```

If I run this query in my terminal, I would get the rejected rows as warnings:

```
 Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '4' for key 'uk-uniquekey'
```

But how could I retrieve them using Go?

Using the returned [`Result`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Result) object, I can get the number of affected rows (and thus find the number of rejected ones), but I need a way to clearly identify these rows.

Also, I have a lot of rows to insert, and I don't want to use an `INSERT` query for each of them.

Are there any good solution for this problem?

---

## Update

I thought of using a single prepared query like this:

```
stmt, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (uniquekey, someotherfield) VALUES (?, ?);")
defer stmt.Close()
for _, element := range elements {
    stmt.Exec(element.UniqueKey, element.SomeOtherField)
}
```

And I benchmarcked this solution, in comparison with the *extended insert* query. For 1000 entries (I admit my machine is not very competitive...), here are my results:

```
Loop on prepared single insert: 10.652721825 s
Single extended insert:          0.092304425 s
```

Considering I have thousands of elements to insert everyday, I can't use this solution either.

Comment: that's the drawback of the "extended" insert syntax. if any of the tuples fail, there's no way to find out WHICH failed. If you need to know what IDs caused dupes, you'll have to run individual single-tuple inserts repeatedly. At that point, you'd be better off using a proper prepared statement, instead of building individual sql strings.

Comment: Even if it would be even nicer, I do not need the index of the rejected tuple: I don't mind parsing the warnings to get the duplicate entries' values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, a couple of things:

- [`github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) appears to define the `MySQLWarnings` type which implements the standard `error` interface so I'm sure it has a way to return these warnings when performing a query or scanning for rows of the result of a query.  I'd dig into the sources to find out.
- MySQL itself supports the [`SHOW WARNINGS` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html) so that you can just query it after performing your `INSERT` statement and iterate over the rows returned.